# Getting a list of Document libraries for the currently login user

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, login

I want to get a list of all the document libraries in the site for the currently login user only?

How can i do this? any code sample if possible?

Comment: Your question has been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219968/how-to-get-list-of-all-document-libraries-from-sharepoint-site-programatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, assign the permission to User on Document Library :

```
    SPDocumentLibrary docLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists["myDocLibrary"];

    docLib.BreakRoleInheritance(false,false); // break inheritance & remove parent permissions

    SPUser spUser = web.EnsureUser("user1");  
    SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(spUser);  
    SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = new SPRoleDefinition();

    roleDefinition = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader); // Give Permission to User on this Document Library

    SPRoleDefinitionBindingCollection roleDefinitionBindingCollection = new SPRoleDefinitionBindingCollection();
    roleDefinitionBindingCollection.Add(roleDefinition);
    roleAssignment.ImportRoleDefinitionBindings(roleDefinitionBindingCollection);
    docLib.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
    docLib.Update();
```

Now, When you will login with user then only those document libraries will be shown which have permission to him. Get all Document Libraries:

```
foreach(SPList list in web.Lists)
{
       try
       {
            if (list.BaseType.ToString() == "DocumentLibrary")
             {
                 // here you get all document library
             }
       }
       catch()
       {}
}
```